# About PCIe enumeration without IO map

Tags: pci-express

I need a help to understand PCIe enumeration

PCIe changes IO mapped IO to memory mapped IO.
PCIe spec introduces Enhanced mechanism for Config read with MMIO.
Since PCIe knows the memory address of configuration register, PCIe uses memory read to do configure read transaction.

During enumeration, PCIe endpoint is not assigned to memory address. (It is even not assigned to BDF.)
To assign BDF, CPU requests a Vendor ID whether PCIe endpoint is valid.
If PCIe endpoint sends a valid Vendor ID, CPU allocate to the BDF for PCIe endpoint and write memory address to Configuration BARs to make memory mapped IO.

To get a Vendor ID, I understand that CPU uses IO write to address port (who is in IO map 0x0CF8), and IO read from data port (who is in IO map 0xCFC).

However, ARM CPU has only memory map (it does not have IO map), then how it request a Vendor ID? What type of TLP packet used?

I would be grateful if you could explain the enumeration process in PCIe packet without IO map.

Comment: Does [Arm Base System Architecture](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/627a76af7e121f01fd22f1fa?token=) section E (pages 53+) have the answer? From my initial read it seems that "PCIe endpoint is not assigned to memory address" is already not true for ARM.